# InfoWindow shouldFocus in Jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

Where and how should I add `InfoWindow.open({anchor: marker, shouldFocus: false});` so that the browser doesn't focus on the Google Map embedded on the web page?

I have seen plenty of examples in plain JS, but I can't get any of them to work with this existing jquery code.

I keep trying, but cannot figure it out.

```
    ! function(e) {
    e.fn.gMap = function(o, a) {
        switch (o) {
            case "addMarker":
                return e(this).trigger("gMap.addMarker", [a.latitude, a.longitude, a.content, a.icon, a.popup]);
            case "centerAt":
                return e(this).trigger("gMap.centerAt", [a.latitude, a.longitude, a.zoom]);
            case "clearMarkers":
                return e(this).trigger("gMap.clearMarkers")
        }
        var n = e.extend({}, e.fn.gMap.defaults, o);
        return this.each(function() {
            var o = new google.maps.Map(this);
            e(this).data("gMap.reference", o);
            var a = new google.maps.Geocoder;
            n.address ? a.geocode({
                address: n.address
            }, function(e) {
                e && e.length && o.setCenter(e[0].geometry.location)
            }) : n.latitude && n.longitude ? o.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(n.latitude, n.longitude)) : e.isArray(n.markers) && n.markers.length > 0 ? n.markers[0].address ? a.geocode({
                address: n.markers[0].address
            }, function(e) {
                e && e.length > 0 && o.setCenter(e[0].geometry.location)
            }) : o.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(n.markers[0].latitude, n.markers[0].longitude)) : o.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(34.885931, 9.84375)), o.setZoom(n.zoom), o.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId[n.maptype]);
            var s = {
                scrollwheel: n.scrollwheel,
                disableDoubleClickZoom: !n.doubleclickzoom
            };
            n.controls === !1 ? e.extend(s, {
                disableDefaultUI: !0
            }) : 0 !== n.controls.length && e.extend(s, n.controls, {
                disableDefaultUI: !0
            }), o.setOptions(s), o.setOptions({
                styles: n.styles
            });
            var t, r, i = new google.maps.Marker;
            t = new google.maps.MarkerImage(n.icon.image), t.size = new google.maps.Size(n.icon.iconsize[0], n.icon.iconsize[1]), t.anchor = new google.maps.Point(n.icon.iconanchor[0], n.icon.iconanchor[1]), i.setIcon(t), n.icon.shadow && (r = new google.maps.MarkerImage(n.icon.shadow), r.size = new google.maps.Size(n.icon.shadowsize[0], n.icon.shadowsize[1]), r.anchor = new google.maps.Point(n.icon.shadowanchor[0], n.icon.shadowanchor[1]), i.setShadow(r)), e(this).bind("gMap.centerAt", function(e, a, n, s) {
                s && o.setZoom(s), o.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(a), parseFloat(n)))
            });
            var g = [];
            e(this).bind("gMap.clearMarkers", function() {
                for (; g[0];) g.pop().setMap(null)
            });
            var l;
            e(this).bind("gMap.addMarker", function(e, a, s, t, r, d) {
                var c, p, m = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(a), parseFloat(s)),
                    h = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: m
                    });
                if (r ? (c = new google.maps.MarkerImage(r.image), c.size = new google.maps.Size(r.iconsize[0], r.iconsize[1]), c.anchor = new google.maps.Point(r.iconanchor[0], r.iconanchor[1]), h.setIcon(c), r.shadow && (p = new google.maps.MarkerImage(r.shadow), p.size = new google.maps.Size(r.shadowsize[0], r.shadowsize[1]), p.anchor = new google.maps.Point(r.shadowanchor[0], r.shadowanchor[1]), i.setShadow(p))) : (h.setIcon(i.getIcon()), h.setShadow(i.getShadow())), t) {
                    "_latlng" === t && (t = a + ", " + s);
                    var w = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: n.html_prepend + t + n.html_append
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(h, "click", function() {
                        l && l.close(), w.open(o, h), l = w
                    }), d && google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(o, "tilesloaded", function() {
                        w.open(o, h)
                    })
                }
                h.setMap(o), g.push(h)
            });
            for (var d, c = this, p = function(o) {
                    return function(a) {
                        a && a.length > 0 && e(c).trigger("gMap.addMarker", [a[0].geometry.location.lat(), a[0].geometry.location.lng(), o.html, o.icon, o.popup])
                    }
                }, m = 0; m < n.markers.length; m++) d = n.markers[m], d.address ? ("_address" === d.html && (d.html = d.address), a.geocode({
                address: d.address
            }, p(d))) : e(this).trigger("gMap.addMarker", [d.latitude, d.longitude, d.html, d.icon, d.popup])
        })
    }, e.fn.gMap.defaults = {
        address: "",
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0,
        zoom: 1,
        markers: [],
        controls: [],
        styles: [],
        scrollwheel: !1,
        doubleclickzoom: !0,
        maptype: "ROADMAP",
        html_prepend: '<div class="gmap_marker">',
        html_append: "</div>",
        icon: {
            image: "https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png",
            shadow: "https://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png",
            iconsize: [20, 34],
            shadowsize: [37, 34],
            iconanchor: [9, 34],
            shadowanchor: [6, 34]
        }
    }
}(jQuery);
```

Comment: You need to modify the `open` calls on any `InfoWindow` objects in your code.  If that doesn't help, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @geocodezip thanks for the reply. Sorry to sound like a dunce, but what do you mean by modify the open calls?

Do you mean these open calls? `w.open(o, h)`

how should I modify them?

Comment: Where is the [mcve]?  (If I am going to write code, I want to test it, and yes, I meant those calls)

Comment: thanks. I'll work on min example. In the meantime, I found that editing the open call to this `w.open({shouldFocus: false})(o, h)` will prevent it from scrolling down to the map, but the infowindow is not open. you have to click the marker to open it.

Comment: I would think using the [documented signature](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindow.open) would work better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves it. Edit this:

```
d && google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(o, "tilesloaded", function() {
                    w.open(o, h)
                })
```

to this:

```
d && google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(o, "tilesloaded", function() {
                    w.open({anchor: h, shouldFocus: false})
                })
```